# django doesnt run a specific migration (it skipped) in production

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-migrations

when I ran the `makemigrations` it returns

```
  users/migrations/0002_remove_profile_image.py
    - Remove field image from profile
```

But when i ran `migrate users 0002..` it said `CommandError: Cannot find a migration matching '0002_remove_profile_image.py' from app 'users'`

when i ran `migrate` it said

```
No migrations to apply.
  Your models in app(s): 'users' have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

what can i do?
i am deploying on heroku

Comment: Remove the `.py`, so just `migrate users 0002_remove_profile_image` or simply `migrate users 0002`

Comment: Have you committed your migrations? _Always_ commit migrations to your version control. We should not generate the migration files on the server itself. Also your files are ephemeral on Heroku, meaning they exist only till the pod exists (which is likely what is happening).

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using the migration name with the `.py`:

```
./manage.py migrate users 0002_remove_profile_image.py
```

But the correct usage is without it, so just remove that:

```
./manage.py migrate users 0002_remove_profile_image
```

or just the short-hand:

```
./manage.py migrate users 0002
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad. I was running with `heroku run` I should have run locally first.